# cannot change state in firebase auth signInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm new in react and firebase. I'm trying to change the value of `isLoggedIn` in `signInWithEmailAndPassword().then()`. But I cannot able to do it, it returns `false` though `setIsLoggedIn(true)` has been called.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import fire from '../config/fire';
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router';
import { Context } from '../../App';

const SignIn = () => {
  const context = useContext(Context);

  // handling state of SignIn
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [emailErr, setEmailErr] = useState('');
  const [passErr, setPassErr] = useState('');
  
  // fetching the previous location
  let history = useHistory();
  let location = useLocation();
  let { previousPath } = location.state || { previousPath: { pathname: '/' } };

  const clearError = () => {
    setEmailErr('');
    setPassErr('');
  };

  const changeHistory = () => {
    if (context.isLoggedIn) {
      history.replace(previousPath);
    }
  };

  const handelSignIn = () => {
    clearError();

    fire
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((res)=> {
        context.setIsLoggedIn(true);
        changeHistory();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        switch (err.code) {
          case 'auth/invalid-email':
            setEmailErr('invalid e-mail, please enter a valid one.');
            break;
          case 'auth/user-not-found':
            setEmailErr('Invalid e-mail address. Please enter the valid one.');
            break;
          case 'auth/wrong-password':
            setPassErr('Invalid password.');
            break;
          default:
            setEmailErr('Something wrong. Please try again.');
            setPassErr('Something wrong. Please try again.');
        }
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>

      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          height: '100vh',
          justifyContent: 'space-around',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <div className="signIn">
          <input
            type="email"
            value={email}
            placeholder="E-mail"
            required
            autoFocus
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
          <p>{emailErr}</p>
          <br/>

          <input
            type="password"
            value={password}
            placeholder="Password"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
          <p>{passErr}</p>
          <br/>

          <button onClick={handelSignIn}>Sign In</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing state is an asynchronous operation. By the time your `changeHistory` is now called, the state hasn't actually been updated yet.

The common way to deal with this, is to use a `useEffect` hook. But in this case it's probably simpler to just pass the state into the call to ``:

```
const changeHistory = (isLoggedIn) => {
  if (isLoggedIn || context.isLoggedIn) {
    history.replace(previousPath);
  }
};

context.setIsLoggedIn(true);
changeHistory(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're calling the `context.setIsLoggedIn(true)` which is asynchronously setting the `isLoggedIn` state inside your context. However, you immediately invoke `changeHistory()` and try to read the `context.isLoggedIn` before it is updated.

If you wish to rely on the updated state, try using a `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(context.isLoggedIn) changeHistory();
 },[context])
```

You can also abstract away this implementation inside your Context Provider instead of keeping this logic inside your component. At any point, you can also read your currently logged in user's details or get the current user is by setting an observer on the Auth object. That's how Firebase recommends you to do it. Refer here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user.